# Amazon Redshift Create External Schema MySQL not enabled

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-aurora-serverless

We are planning to use Amazon Redshift and planning to use Federated Queries to connect and insert data from our Aurora RDS (MySQL, Provisioned). I followed this documentation to setup the secrets manager store, IAM role for redshift, security group etc.:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/getting-started-federated-mysql.html

So now when I try to run the query CREATE EXTERNAL SCHEMA .... FROM MYSQL, I get this error message:

ERROR: CREATE EXTERNAL SCHEMA .. FROM MYSQL is not enabled.

I am running this examples on Redshift Query Editor.

Example query from documentation:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL SCHEMA <schema_name>
FROM MYSQL
DATABASE '<database_name>'
URI '<endpoint_of_rds>'
IAM_ROLE '<iam_role_attached_to_redshift>'
SECRET_ARN '<secret_arn_contains_rds_credentials>';
```

I tried to go around Redshift console to check for any setting to enable it but could not find any. Anyone familiar with the setup?

Only question asked so far is this but it is using redshift spectrum: [What are the steps to use Redshift Spectrum.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44646788/what-are-the-steps-to-use-redshift-spectrum)

Please advise. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Federated queries are in **preview** [at the momement](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_EXTERNAL_SCHEMA.html):

> The following is prerelease documentation for the federated query to MySQL feature for Amazon Redshift, which is in **preview release**.

This means that you have to explicit set your cluster to enable preview features.

You do this by [setting maintenance track of your cluster](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/announcing-amazon-redshift-federated-querying-to-amazon-aurora-mysql-and-amazon-rds-for-mysql/) to `sql_preview`.

Comment: I missed that info! Makes more sense now... Thank you for that information!

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that this feature is coming out of preview very soon/already. According to the AWS redshift forums:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=8900

Although I should add that I get the same 'not enabled' error and my cluster version is now 1.0.31186, so I'm not sure what's going on with that.

Also this should be a a reply to Marcin's answer but I lack the reputation to use such features.